# Inet Socket Omnet++

Tags: sockets, omnet++

I include TCPSOcket.h header in my project.

But when i try to use the object

**TCPSocket mysocket;**

and build the project,  get the following error : **'TCPSocket was no declared in this scope'**

Any suggestions?

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please help us help you by posting what you have tried so far (i.e. a code snippet of the file which is not compiling). For additional suggestions, please see: [How do I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INET` uses C++ namespace `inet` so in your code you should add the namaspace before a class name, for example

```
inet::TCPSocket mysocket;
```

Or you can put your whole code within `namespace inet`, for example:

```
namespace inet {

    Define_Module(PC);

    void PC::initialize() {
      TCPSocket mysocket;
      // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of INET do you use?

If you implement code directly in INET (in source files located in the INET src folder or modifications to existing INET files), did you make sure that the complete path to the header file is inserted? For example for INET version 3.5:

```
#include "inet/transportlayer/contract/tcp/TCPSocket.h"
```

This behavior changed in current OMNeT versions, as the deep search magic for include files was removed (in version 5.1 and its beta and release candidates) in favor for includes with the complete path starting from the project root directory.

If you have a separate project, did you check that the INET project is referenced? Also, your include path would look different, because your sources are in a different root folder compared to the separated INET project.

Are you using namespaces? If so, did you check for any inconsistencies there?

Answer (score 0):

I use Omnet++ 5.0

I have a separate project, and yes I referenced the inet project in my project's properties.

My project is in the same workspace as INET. This is a little of my code, where i use a TCP object:

```
#include "PC.h"
#include "myHeader_m.h"
#include "TCPSocket.h"

Define_Module(PC);

void PC::initialize()
{
    cMessage * reminder = new cMessage("Interval");
    .....
    .....
    .....
    //TCPSocket msocket = new TCPSocket();
    TCPSocket mysocket;

}
```

This is the include Path in makefile

```
# C++ include paths (with -I)
INCLUDE_PATH = -I../inet/src -I../inet/src/inet/transportlayer/contract/tcp -I. -Iresults
```